# Como "montar" uma variável múltipla?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, variáveis, asp.net-core

Seria possível eu montar uma variável para passar um valor a ela? Por exemplo:

```
var teste0 = "valor";
var teste1 = "outro valor";
var teste2 = "mais um valor";

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    teste+i = "mudou "+i;
}
```

Repare no `teste+i`. Mesmo já esperando que não desse certo, tentei desta forma e estava errado.

Tem alguma maneira de eu montar a variável como na ideia do exemplo?

Comment: Não tem como você montar uma variável assim. Utilize arrays ou coleções para isto.

Comment: Se essas variáveis forem todas do mesmo tipo, um array ou uma lista genérica resolvem.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves são todas do mesmo tipo, mas no caso eu estou recebendo elas para passar para outra. Por exemplo, `var nome0 = "Ronaldo"; var data0 = "16/07/1995"; var nome1 = "Pedro"; var data1 = "16/07/1998"; for(int i=0; i<2;i++){ var frase = "O " nome+i + " nasceu no dia " data+i; }`. Algo parecido entende?

Comment: Como essas variáveis se tratam do mesmo elemento, talvez seja interessante criar uma classe para elas. Ex: Classe `Pessoa` com propriedades `Nome` e `DataNascimento`. Daí você usa uma `List<Pessoa>`

Comment: Realmente você deve repensar a lógica por "montar nome da variável".

Comment: @edro Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível, é uma das técnicas mais básicas e conhecidas da programação. Você faz isso com uma variável do tipo *array*. Um *array* é uma variável que guarda variáveis e assim você consegue acessá-las exatamente da mesma forma, só a sintaxe ligeiramente diferente.

Não use um dicionário para isto, ele é totalmente desnecessário, lento, improdutivo e inseguro, menos ainda use reflexão ou soluções mais complexas que tem os mesmos problemas de forma acentuada (ou seja as soluções das outras duas respostas). Olha que simples, seguro e performático:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var teste = new string[] {"valor", "outro valor", "mais um valor" };
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) teste[i] = "mudou " + i;
        foreach(var item in teste) WriteLine(item );
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/P2s9KA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ory7xe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Variables.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria para esta situação você utilize um dicionário de string.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("teste0", "valor");
dictionary.Add("teste1", "outro valor");
dictionary.Add("teste2", "mais um valor");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["teste" + i.ToString()]);
}
```

Comment: Esse código não vai compilar. Você está chamando `i.ToString()` e não `Teste + i`. Deve-se colocar entre parenteses para executar a expressão. Além disso, `i` não está declarado. `for(i = 0` passa a ser `for(int i = 0`.

Comment: Corrigido, famoso ctrl+c e ctrl+v. Obrigado.